# Javascript Button in HTML on player

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I have the following

```
jwplayer('player').addButton(
                  "https://imgur.com/ZPRchL3.png",
                  "openlink when clicked",
                   function() {
                   onclick="location.href='link';
                  },
                 "openlinkwhenclicked"
                );
```

i am trying to add to my JWPLAYER a extra button so when its clicked it opens the link but its not showing any idea what i have coded wrong?

Comment: Remove `onclick="`, not sure why that is there.

Comment: I guess the fuction should actually open the link instead of setting value to variable. Try to add inside the function - `window.open(link, '_blank');`

Comment: window.open(https://blahblah.com, '_blank')";  ?

Comment: Works thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If this is your exact code, you are missing a quotation (") at the end of the `onclick="location.href='link'";` This may be your issue

Comment: When clicked tho the button does nothing it dont actually open a link hmm